# How can I take the information I received with linq and use that information in an if else statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this `LINQ` that works just fine:

```
var checkIFExist = (from row in db.Following
                      where follow.UserName == checkUserNameInLinq 
                         && follow.FollowThisUser == FollowUsername 
                         && follow.isFollowing == true
                      select row).ToList();
```

If all values are correct, I would like to use them in an if else statement.
for example:

```
if (checkIFExist == ALL 3 VALUES IN LINQ IS CORRECT)
{
   Index();
}
```

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are asking here. What does `ALL 3 VALUES IN LINQ IS CORRECT` mean? Do you have a list of items that you want to compare that should be returned by your Linq query? Take a look at the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for some ideas on how to write a good question that will be more likely to get answered.

Comment: have you looked at the linq `All()` method? E.g. `if (checkIfExist.All(c => c.boolToCheck))`

Comment: Your query will only return *any* element if all three of your conditions are passed. So If `checkIfExists` contains any elements, you could process with your `Index`-method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linq query returns rows which meet your conditions:

```
var rowsMeetingCriteria = from row in db.Following
                          where (... conditions ...)
                          select row;
```

Now, on which condition do you want to perform an action? If you want to do something if there's at least one row retunred by the query, use .Any() method:

```
if (rowsMeetingCriteria.Any())
{
    // code
}
```

If you have any other needs, take a look at [methods available for Enumerables here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). You can also put your query inside the Any method, like below, but when the query has few parts you should probably do it separately as above (better readability):

```
if (rowsMeetingCriteria.Any(row => row.Field1 == ... && row.Field2 > ...)
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: That's great @JaneTheDotNet Please mark the answer as accepted, so others will know that it solves the problem.